# Access Violation unless I clean before recompile

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am receiving an access violation after I recompile a certain unit (MyClass) unless I do a clean.  The error is clearly a call to a null object (Write of address 00000000), but when I try to step to it, the compiler won't allow me to step into the code where I think the error is occurring. (Inside a method on the same object.  When i trace into the method, there error after hitting trace into but before going to the line of code.)  This happens in a used unit of MyClass, rather than MyClass itself.

The weird thing is that if I do a clean (or build) and then recompile, the program runs fine.  Any reason this would happen?

**Update**

The application uses several threads created via the AsyncCalls library.  I use several `TEvent` and `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` objects to keep processes ordered and resources protected.  Does any special care need to be taken when creating or freeing such objects?

Comment: may on the disk be mseveral copies of xxxxx.pas ? you can try to trace in CPU Window even if debug info was missed

Comment: Are you using multiple projects against the code base? Or change project options such as compiler directives?

Comment: @Arioch'The I have verified that there are no duplicate XXX.pas in any of my source directories. What would I look for in the CPU window to be helpful?

Comment: @Steve Only one project on the code base.  I don't recall making any changes except to turn off optimizations on the debug build.

Comment: nothinng, just if those functions are simple and mostly are using other functions, then asm code can be debugged too. Not that comfort as pascal code, yet possible. Since exe is monolithic it is very strange that only SOME units lack debuginfo. But i dunno what is special about them. As a blind shot you my find your exe in view / debug / modules and issue "reload symbols" on it. That sometimes helps with BPLs but never heard of such trouble with single EXE

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Output-Path in Project-Settings.
Set an Output-Path (e.g. ".\$(Config)\_dcu") for compiled Units and then check again.

Comment: Nope.  This is said.  And as I mentioned, it only happens if I modify the source code to a certain unit (or it's dependencies).  Not at every recompile, so many times it works.  Others not.  (However, the unit specific thing makes me suspicious of myself....)

Comment: my suggestion is delete all the DCU's.. then try to rebuild all

Comment: Nope.  Deleting the dcu's didn't get it either. (Side note: I guess that's what I thought a clean was doing. What does a clean accomplish?)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what a clean does. It removes all dcu's for a executable project. For packages it removes all dcp's and bpls that the project will create. Sense the av is typically related to a nil pointer you may need do dig through the sections of code you feel could be causeing it and make sure a referenced object is created or you are not double freeing somthing. Basicly try to find in your code where an object may be referenced but could be nil when it is being referenced.... If that made sense... I'm a little slow this morning so this might be hard to interprete.

Comment: @JeremyEvans But why would doing a clean eliminate the error?

Comment: But what is some stray DCUs remain in folders not in path now ? then clean command could miss it, and make command could sometimes catch them. OTO that can be easily checked with SysInternals Process Monitor.  In legacy Delphi sometimes "generate Td32 info" or "generate remote symbols" could help. But modern Delphi IDEs seem to no more support those kinds of debug info

Comment: Are you using any type of threading or COM interfaces? Also are you generating any feedback loops, I.E have code in an event that triggeres another event, which in turn returns yet another event? Also of you use application processmessages in your application is can cause areas of your code to be called when you did not intened it to be called.

Comment: @JeremyEvans : Yes.  There is threading going on, currently using the AsyncCalls library. I also use `TEvent` and `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` objects a lot.  Threads frequently wait for events to trigger, and in turn trigger other events.  I do not make any calls to Application.ProcessMessages however.  Is there more to managing these event objects than I'm aware of?

Comment: @EricG I had a similar issue, it has something to do with the order of units in "uses"... it's a witch hunt but it may just save you a ton of wasted time...